# React: generic and typed onChange() handler

Tags: reactjs, typescript, onchange

Adding `as HTMLInputElement` fixes the `Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'EventTarget & (HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement)'.` error, but given the type check I am wondering why TS doesn't automatically infer e.currentTarget to be a checkbox.

```
const onChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
        const { name, type } = e.currentTarget
        const value: string | number | boolean = type === 'checkbox' ? (e.currentTarget as HTMLInputElement).checked : e.currentTarget.value
        setState({ ...state, [name]: value })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `type` is just `string`, not a union of string literals, so it is inappropriate to use as a type discriminator.

Given that docs for `type` say

> Returns the content type of the object

I think you are mistaken in using this value at all.

If you want to correctly narrow the type here then:

```
const value: string | number | boolean =
    'checked' in e.currentTarget ? e.currentTarget.checked : e.currentTarget.value;
```

will do the trick.